# how to extract word frequency for a subset of words in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining, word-frequency

I have a dataframe with about 10,000 words in one column and their corresponding frequencies in another. I also have a vector with about 600 words. Each of the 600 words is a word in the data frame. How do I look up the frequencies for the 600-word vector from the 10,000 word data frame?

Comment: `match` or `merge`.

Comment: Suggested R-FAQ duplicate [how to join data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/903061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dplyr`'s join functions.

```
# make the 600 vector into a dataframe
600_df <- as.data.frame(600_vec)

# left join the two dataframes
df <- left_join(x = 600_df, y = 10000_df, by = "word")
```

where the "word" is the variable name constant between the two dataframes

Answer (score 0):

One of the many solutions, with `df$words` being the column of your data.frame with the words and `wordsvector` being the vector:

```
library(plyr)
freqwords <- ddply(df, .(words), summarize, n = length(words)) #shows frequency of all the words in the data.frame
freqwords[freqwords$words %in% wordsvector,] #keeping only the words that appear in your vector
```

Next time it would be helpful if you provide some dummy data so we can help you better.